# Submit http GET request without going to new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm new to this community and quite new to coding so please forgive any inappropriate content or question.

I am building a small CRM system with mysql as the back end to be accessed via a website.

I would like to integrate our telephone system into this so that when I load a page with client information I can click a button on the page and the user's handset will dial the client's telephone number.

We use Yealink handsets which can be remotely controlled with an http GET request.

I have got all of the above working except that irritatingly when the button is clicked on the form to dial the client, a new page is opened with the GET request shown in the address bar. I then have to click the "Back" button on the browser to get back to the client information page.

My objective is for the GET request to execute in the background without changing the page displayed.

The syntax for the GET request that is sent to the Yealink handset takes the form:

http://user:password@192.168.xxx.xxx/servlet?key=number=01234567890&outgoing_uri=1

and I have encoded this into an html form as follows:

```
<form method="POST">

<input type="text" name="Tel1" value="<?php echo $datacus['Tel1'] ?>" placeholder="Telephone 1">
<a href="http://user:password@<?php echo $phoneip; ?>/servlet?key=number=<?php echo $datacus['Tel1']; ?>&outgoing_uri=1"><button type="button" action="submit">Call</button></a> 

</form>
```

where the variables are retrieved from the mysql database.

This all works perfectly except, as explained above, on clicking the button I am taken, to another page.  I don't require any information back from the GET request - it merely sends the command to a handset which then instigates the call.

I've spent some time going around in circles on this (mainly looking at the information that very knowledgeable contributors to this forum have contributed), so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:ajax] so use Ajax. That's what Ajax means. There are many, many tutorials out there.

Comment: 1) GET requests should not change the state, so not modify stuff in the database, session, cookies, ... Otherwise your website is prone to XSRF 2) If the request changes the state, it **MUST** be a POST, PUT or DELETE 3) If you get CORS errors when sending an ajax, it means the ajax response doesn't contain a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (or similar) that allows your website. So this webservice you're calling should be modified for this!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response Quentin.

The problems that I appear to have with ajax (or anything that in essence uses xmlhttp) are twofold.  Firstly the url to which I am sending the response will only accept http and not https.  This is a "black box" that cannot be changed.  The second is that it is on a domain that is external to the server.  The browser that I am using throws up various CORS and domain origin errors when any script is run client side.  I was hoping to find a way to send the http GET request from the server side (in php ?) rather than the client (browser) side as no response is needed.  Thank you.